# .htaccess Help For Multiple Get Variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my URL to look like:
localhost/website/148/category

Here is my .htaccess file at the moment

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.*)$ /website/index.php?id=$1&c=$2
```

Can anyone help me? I have been looking around forever for the answer and so far nothing has worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the htaccess file is in the website directory, obviously that changes what the rules need to be.

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /website/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /website/index.php?id=$1&c=$2
```

As far as fixing the relative links for your CSS and images etc, you need to correct your relative URI base by putting this in the header of you pages:

```
<base href="/website/">
```

Comment: Didn't work, I am really confused, I can get it to work with only one GET variable

Comment: @user1672744 you didn't indicate where your htaccess file was, which is pretty important, see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ /website/index.php?id=$1&c=$2
```

Comment: No it didn't work, still telling me that the page doesn't exist,

Comment: i'm not sure for your directory structure. Whould you show it?

Comment: I have a directory called "website" then I have a few sub folders for my database connect and my css, but all my other files are all in the same folder. Except I do have images that I am retrieving from a folder called "uploads", that is what the "148" is for in the url above. But thats about it.

Comment: hmm, it didn't tell me that the page didn't exist this time, but it didn't load any of the data or css.. What do you think would cause that?

Comment: I cant tell before see the files. what is the url?

Comment: i cant see your localhost :). You need to provide me either ip or domain name

Comment: If you use relative paths to load css and other stuff, it will fail, when you use .htaccess, you should use absolute path for all the links like http://localhost/css/mycssfile.css

Comment: I'm not really sure what your asking? I am new to all of this kind of stuff.